# How to save a movie/animation to OpenEXR?

Tags: rendering, animation

OpenEXR Multilayer can store many frames in one file, so it should be possible to store many render passes for the whole strip when rendering animation or movie. However when I check in *Properties->Render->Output* -- there is no such option as to store movie in OpenEXR Multilayer. If I select OpenExr Multilayer and then render animation -- I get multiple EXR files instead of one.

What should I do to save movie to OpenEXR Multilayer format?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406

Answer (score 3):

You just render the movie to an image sequence.

OpenEXR is intended for still images, I'm not sure of the benefit of storing an entire animation in a single OpenEXR file, as far as I know, no other applications use OpenEXR this way either (feel free to correct me, but I didn't hear of anyone doing this).

Comment: It is possible to use it for animation, and benefits of it are shown at http://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/12/10/compositing-cycles-render-passes-blender/

Comment: Yep, its possible, just as you could store animation in any multi-layer format XCF/PSD/TIFF (multipage). But its not a common workflow (AFAIK) and Blender doesn't support - doubtless with enough effort some hack can be done to support it, but Im not sure what the benefit would be - could existing software even play it back?

Comment: I would like to use it for compositing of animation, and then save to something else. The same way as I use it for compositing of stills and then save to jpeg or png

Comment: @dimus, use image sequences, blender supports these just fine (with start-end frames), this is standard workflow for compositing.

Comment: @dimus In virtually every compositing package, OpenEXR file is used in a sequence, each file contains render passes of *a single frame*. It is possible to use for animation, just not in the way you intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Open EXR to save render for compositing you don't need to save all the frames to a single .exr file. The Image node can handle multiple .exr files. When creating the Image node in the compositor select all the generated .exr files. The image node will then present you with fields for setting the frame offset and looping options etc...