# How to use index passes in other compositing packages?

Tags: node-editor, export, compositing-nodes

In Blender there is a 'Mask ID Node' in the 'Compositor' to extract **IndexOB or IndexMA** of a *Multilayer EXR*. But how to work with these passes in other compositing packages? In e.g. Nuke or After Effects there is **nothing like an ID Node**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work in **all other packages** you need to **manually** create [custom output channels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-render-passes-to-a-exr-with-blender-2-71/18406#18406) and **append the passes to your Multilayer EXR** via Blenders *Compositor*:

[image]

---

In Nuke you can use [J_Ops](http://www.nukepedia.com/plugins/other/j_ops/). With this tool **you don't need the additional node setup** above. There is a tool called **J_GotSomeID** which is able to detect such IDs from the EXR Multilayer automatically.

1. **Select the pass** (IndexOB or IndexMA)
2. Set the **Selection Mode to Find**
3. To detect the IDs click **Autofill**

[image]