# How can I add inputs to a file output node?

Tags: rendering, interface, node-editor, compositing-nodes

New to Blender. How to add additional inputs to the file output node?

This post doesn't explain:
[How can I render all render passes to files in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've edited your question a little to try and make it more concise. If you disagree with my edits, feel free to rollback or [edit] them

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the *Add Input* button in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) when the file output node is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i didn't have the properties panel open. The interface still confuses me :)