# How to chose the format for the File Output Node?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

In the Compositor, there is this node called `File Output` node that allows output additional files :

[image]

They are very useful when you want to render extra passes or just render the output of a node without using the Composite Node.

The problem is that, I don't know of any way to explicitly chose the format of the output files since we just have `Add` > `Output` > `File Output` and then you just have the node with the file type written on it but no option to change besides the location of the file.

Now, I know that the file type is by default the same as the file output in the Render Settings but when I chose a video output format there, all the File Output nodes that I create are OpenEXR format so I have to set the Render Settings back to PNG then, create a File Output node and then set the Render Settings back to FFMPEG Video, this is still doable but it gets really annoying if you need to customize the output settings for the file like adding alpha channel, changing compression ratio etc...

Is there any way to change the format of the File Output node without going to Render Settings?

If we can use a different file format than the one in the Render Settings, wouldn't it make sense that we have a way to set the file format without changing the Render Settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33885/115533) actually pointed me to the right direction.

This is a bit stupid but I never thought of going to the N panel to check for additional options :

[image]

There is actually settings there that lets you chose the file format with all the render settings that I was looking for.