# Export render from Cycles as floating point RGB in scene linear color space?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, file-format, color-management

Is there an easy way to access (and hopefully export) the rawest output from Cycles, namely the rendered image as RGB(A) floats in scene linear color space?

Comment: "Scene linear" is not a colour space. Scene referred imaging is linearized, but is not a fully qualified colour space due to the fact that any RGB scene referred system can be linearized; it would require defining the RGB primaries to be a fully fledged colour space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes!

You can export the image in OpenEXR format, it will save the information as scene linear. You can choose to save as Half Float (16-bit floating-point} or as Full 32-bit floating-point.

In the basic OpenEXR format you can save RGBA + Z depth information.

Using OpenEXR multilayer you can save all of your layers and render passes on the same file.

To save all of your layers you need a file output node and create the links to the layer pass information you want to save.

To set it up please read:

[Save all render passes to a single EXR image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image)

and

[How can I render all render passes to files in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles/28764#28764)

More info on OpenEXR format here: http://www.openexr.com/