# Combining .exr files?

Tags: compositing-nodes, file-format, .exr

Is it possible to composite multiple .exr files into a single .exr file?

For example, if one .exr file contains several passes and another contains only one pass could they be combined to contained all in one file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can load several EXRs on the compositor and save all of their channels into individual layers on an OpenEXR multilayer.

Add a [**file output node**](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/output/file.html?highlight=file%20output), set it to **[OpenEXR muyltilayer](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html#image-formats)** and than add as many inputs as you need.

[image]

You can rename the channels as needed by double clicking on the name:

[image]

For more details see this answers:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18406/1853

[How can I render all render passes to files in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles/28764#28764)

Comment: Just a tip for anyone pretty new to blender, to edit a node's settings like above:

Comment: 1. Select the node

Comment: 2. Open the node settings panel with N

Comment: Sometimes the node settings panel is hidden, try using the hotkey if you are having trouble finding it.