# Export multi-pass .exr image sequence from cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, file-format, render-passes, .exr

Is it possible to export an image sequence (in this case a sequence of .exrs) from cycles?

For example, I have multiple sets of .exrs for different passes I want to combine into one set of .exr image sequences.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53300/combining-exr-files/53301#53301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save all the passes for each frame into a multilayer OpenEXR:

Add an Input>Image Sequence node and use that to import the OpenEXR sequence

Add an Output>File Output Node and set it to Use OpenEXR multilayer and plug the outputs of the Image sequence to it.

You still need a valid output for the render. So create a dummy file, a jpeg file will do. You can erase those later.

[image]

Then just set your frame range and render as animation (ctrl F12)

(and remember to erase the jpeg dummy files)

Comment: I set up my node layout similar to your setup but I'm having trouble rendering out a series of .exr files at the end with all of the passes within each .exr in the series. (Link to setup: http://i.imgur.com/uQtVKAV.png)

When I render one frame everything works great, you get one .exr with several passes. When you try to render out the sequence you get .exrs with a combined pass and one other random pass. Did I set something up wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Preview of what's inside the .exr files: http://i.imgur.com/s2rMSwJ.png

The first image is the first frame when rendered separately. The second is when it is rendered as an animation.

Comment: See edited answer