# How can I update a specific layer of a multilayer exr file?

Tags: render-layers, .exr

Is it possible to "update" parts of a multilayer exr while retaining other render layers?

Let's say I have two layers A and B. I render both layers to the same exr and later I decide to re-render layer B (with option "Only render the active layer" checked). When I click on "Animate", Blender overwrites all existing exr files, so layer A is lost. I don't want to re-render all layers, since it's pretty time-consuming.

Do I have to use multiple exr files - one for each layer - to fix this? What's the benefit of the multilayer exr then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to render out a new OpenEXR file.

Bring the OpenEXR files you already rendered into the compositor using an image sequence node. Then add a [file output node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/output/file.html?highlight=file%20output) and set it to [OpenEXR multilayer](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/image_formats.html?highlight=openexr#openexr). Reroute the outputs to combine the images as needed and re-render the sequence.

[image]

The basic procedure to setup the OpenEXR layers is outlined on this post:[Combining .exr files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53301/1853)

[image]

You might need to render out a set of dummy files to automate the rendering.
See this post:[Export multi-pass .exr image sequence from cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/export-multi-pass-exr-image-sequence-from-cycles/53604#53604)