# How to render layers in different files?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

To explain myself better, i have 3 render layers (i’m using blender 2.8) one with the subject, one with a light beam and the last one with the background.
This is an animation and i want to composite each layer in premiere separately, how can i render 3 different images per frame? Thanks!

Comment: Use a file node or a multilayer OpenEXR file See: 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/export-multi-pass-exr-image-sequence-from-cycles/53604#53604