# Image Output Filetype for Compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I am working on an animation and am rendering it out as an image sequence, currently .png. However, .png loses a lot of the information native to the render, such as render pass data and so on. This makes compositing the image sequence after the fact a bit tricky.

What image format can I use to preserve this data so I can have all of the same options for my image sequence as I would for the Render Result?

Comment: You should use the .exr format : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/export-multi-pass-exr-image-sequence-from-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OpenEXR](https://www.openexr.com/) multilayer.

[image]

Think of EXR as a perfect copy of the render layers. Multilayer will allow you to save all of the different passes.

EXR will keep your information linear and un-distorted by color transforms, with the proper associated alpha channel and the z pass as unbound data.

Enable the render passes that you want in the view layer.

[image]

Use a File Output node, create as many layers as you need with the Add input button. Then plug the output sockets of each of the render layers you want to save.

[image]

Png is a terrible format, never meant for compositing.

Comment: Further explanation can be found here: [Save all render passes to a single EXR image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406)

Comment: So I can include as many or as few passes as I want? That is quite nice indeed! Thank you!