# Is there a way to auto name my AOV outputs?

Tags: python, scripting, eevee-render-engine, command-line, render-passes

So in most other software I use like Houdini and C4D there are tokens you can use to assign auto naming conventions such as the `$` (dollar sign) expression.

In C4D `$prj` will name the output name as the project name. or in Houdini `$OS.F` will name the output as the "OperatorString.FrameNumber"

Is there anything in Blender that can make outputs a lot easier than manually naming stuff all the time?

Comment: You might want to try [Loom](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom), added a simple [global variable system](https://devtalk.blender.org/uploads/default/original/3X/1/e/1e0cc308c9254a8ae0ec3a1158794321cb89fedd.png) to the *User Prefernces* recently as well as a *version* property based on [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127573/how-do-i-stop-the-compositor-output-node-from-overwriting-my-images-on-each-new/135494#135494). Unfortunately, I hadn't the time to document the features yet but I think all should be quite familiar to you.