# Z-combine multiple openExr and render with passes

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, .exr

Lets say I rendered 2 different openexr images with some passes and now I want to z-combine them and save them as 1 openexr image with the same passes, how do I do that? I'm using cycles
I tried the following, but it only saves it as combine, not with passes?
[image]

Comment: by plugging the combined image to a composite node you are only saving the result of the Z-combine and all other information is getting lost. Use a File Output node and create sockets for as many layers as you want to save. Read; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image adn https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53300/combining-exr-files/53301#53301

Comment: but I need to combine those two images as well using z-combine. How will i combine other passes?

Comment: Each pass is an individual layer. You would need to use Z-combine in each layer that you want to combine and then save them as a separate layer by using the File Output node.