# Remove frame number from file name completely in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, file-format

I am working on a single frame where I'd like to create one file for each pass without numbers attached. For example I'd like to name a pass AO.png instead of AO0001.png or AO1.png.

I saw you can shorten the name down to AO1.png with AO#.png but if possible I'd like to remove the numbers completely.

Comment: This question is unclear, you can "edit" it to add more information. If you're going to render an image sequence, you are going to have multiple images, e.g. AO1.png, AO2.png, AO3.png. What do you want instead? AO.png, AO.png, AO.png?

Comment: Do you know, that once you render a single frame (F12) and press F3, you can save it with a prompted name?

Comment: @Leander I didn't know that, thanks for the tip!

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: @poor I think mainly because I prefer AO.png to AO1.png. I guess it's just a perfectionist thing. It really doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Animatoring For perfection I'd suggest render to [**exr multilayer**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28764/3710) :) Otherwise you can try [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) to batch rename your files.