# Render passes for image sequence

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation

I wanna use the glare node in cycles but the render passes for the image sequence is saved only for the last frame,
I tried disabling the combined pass and changing the file format to OpenEXR but it still doesn't prompt image sequence upload in the render layers

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles/28764#28764