# How to load a render from cloud-servis into compositor with passes?

Tags: import, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I have a cloud rendered png image and I cannot find a way to load that rendered image into compositor as render layers. Of course i can import image with image node but, I cannot use passes like depth, AO, Mist etc. Also I cannot see that image as backdrop image. I have shared a screenshot in which you can see that image node doesn't have that many output pins.

**How do I import my cloud rendered image in compositor to use all passes?**

[image: screenshot of imported image]

Comment: PNG is a terrible format for what you want to do, It doesn't contain any of the infornation you want, and even if you saved many different passes as different images the images are  of limited use as they are in display referred values. You need a format that keeps your scene referred data linear and unbound, and that can also save different layers. EXR multilayer is the only one that will work for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to render into **OpenEXR  Multilayer** (.EXR) output format to keep passes in saved file.
(PNG can't store these layers / passes.)

[image]

To see *Backdrop* you have to connect *Viewer* node.
(with *Node Wrangler* addon enabled, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>)

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles/28764#28764

Comment: @susu ah :) so we can close it as dupli. I wasnt sure if there is not an issue also with some cloud servis limitations, but since accepted, no reason to keep it I would say.

Comment: No need to close as duplicate. The post answers the question correctly and informative. I just like to leave links for users to find information if they wish to use it (most just ignore links, but maybe it will help others).