# How to render shadows only in 2.91

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, shadows, shadowcatcher

I have finished a building, and I'd like to render it in Cycles:

1. As it is with shadows: I know how to do it. I've done it and it looks great.
2. As it is without shadows: I know how to do it, I just untag 'Cast Shadow'.
3. Only with shadows: I don't know how to make the mesh dissapear from the render and render only the shadows. This is where I'm struggling. I tried to find help online but they're all old guides from a different version of Blender. I also found ways to do it with Nodes, but the question is: Where do I set up the node system? In the World, Object or Line Style? And how, because if I set it up on the World it will overwrite the other nodes that I use for texturing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I remember correctly you can set it to render separate passes. Here's a similar question from stack exchange https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles

Comment: View layer, light part, check shadow and get it in the compositor from a render layer node. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/render_layers.html

Comment: Hi lemon, I found the way to get to the render layer node, but it doesn't work the nodes im using to render only shadows