# Is there a way to automatically change output file suffix per frame image based on the timeline marker label?

Tags: scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

Background: I'm trying to automate as much as I can for a small business, I have. I use blender to create product marketing material, because there are so many variations, it's cost prohibitive to photograph them for real.

I make books with images on them, but each image can be on many cover types. I have it set up so that I key framed the render restrict function so that I can render an animation where all cover types cycle through with the image.

But I have to manually change the naming scheme so its more legible because I'm dealing with hundreds of files. Luckily I only have to change only about 5 or 6 images at a time, but I plan on expanding.

So, Is there a way to automatically change output file suffix per frame image based on the timeline marker label?

[image: Blender Screen With Timeline]

For Example, instead of just cover, it would output Cover_WinterWhite for frame 1 and Cover_GodlyGold for Frame 3

I have searched for a while and came up empty handed. The manual only references padded numbers and being able to change them with the wanted number of # symbols, but no mention of any functionality for adding any generated string.

If not possible, any chance you've heard of an add on that can do this?

Edit 1: @Ratt commented a [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/is-it-possible-to-set-the-output-name-based-on-the-current-timeline-marker?rq=1) that is a very close answer to my question. I will try to add to the script to fit my need exactly and post the answer here. If you post an answer here for it before me, I'll will select it as the answer.

Just to clarify, the difference between the linked answer and my question, is that I need the marker label to be concatenated to a base string. Otherwise, I have to change the marker labels manually anyway, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/is-it-possible-to-set-the-output-name-based-on-the-current-timeline-marker?rq=1) [similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42661/render-objects-to-separate-files-using-python/48071#48071)

Comment: @Ratt Thank you so much, your related link really is so close. Can't believe I missed it. I will definitely be using it as a base for trying to create a script of my own to complete what exactly I need.