# How to render individual objects (one per frame)

Tags: objects, render-layers, units

I have a quick question for anyone who may know...

I have in my scene multiple objects and I want to render each of them individually.

Is there any possibility to render each of them individually without putting them one by one in another layer and rendering it?(I have 58 objects...)
I want to make an animation in 58 frames where in every frame there will appear just one of them.

I've put a unique index on every object, and I want for example... in frame 1 to display just the object with index 1 and so on..

If anyone knows please tell me, thx :D

Comment: I cant put 58 objects... each of them in another layer... rly now

Comment: You have one for every single frame?? You can use the material index pass in compositing, but I think there is probably a better way to do what you are doing. We need more information :/

Comment: If you need to use the material index pass, I can write an answer later tday.

Comment: I have an electronic scheme and I need each of his elements in another image... How can I render it using material index?

Comment: Do they overlap?

Comment: no, they don't overlap

Comment: Give them all a unique material ID, and use the node I  the compositor to separate them

Comment: k, I will try it, thx for idea :D

Comment: @J.D related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42204/how-to-output-id-masks-as-seperate-files-for-compositing/42209#42209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by assigning an Object ID index to each object that corresponds to the frame in which you want the object to appear.

Then in the compositor, you set the alpha channel using the IDMask node. The trick is to then add a driver to the Index value so that it uses the frame number as the Index value on each frame change.

[image]

To add the driver, right click on the Index field in the ID Mask node, and select Add Driver. Then, with the node still selected, open the Graph Editor and switch to Driver view. The default driver type is Scripted Expression, and all you need to do is enter the value "frame" in the Expr field of the driver settings. Now when you change the active frame on the timeline, the ID Mask node will update the alpha channel to filter out all other objects and just show the object with the Object Index ID that matches the current frame number.