# Is there an equivalent of MODO's "save layered image" in Cycles?

Tags: rendering

I'm so new to Blender. I used only Modo before. There is "save layered image" which saves alpha masks per mesh you want if you added alpha output to these meshes before. This psd opens with different layers with alpha masks in photoshop.
Is there an equivalent of this in Cycles?
How can I save render with alpha outputs per each mesh?
Sorry for my bad English(

Comment: ... not sure if it suits your needs but Blender supports OpenEXR multilayered, and there are plugins for Photoshop tto (see http://www.openexr.com/downloads.html) and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html

Comment: There is, in Blender they are called *[Render Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html)* you must set them up before rendering so each desired object gets assigned to the corresponding layer. The as mentioned by m.ardito save the render as OpenEXR to save a single image file with multiple layers.

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18243/how-to-use-index-passes-in-other-compositing-packages/18247#18247 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-i-render-all-render-passes-to-files-in-cycles/28764#28764