# How to access render layers?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I'm rendering static images in Blender under Windows 10 and I want to have all the render layers available for post-processing, etc.
My problem is that the render layers are available only so long as the .blend file remains open after the render; once I save the .blend file and close Blender, then re-open the same .blend file, the render layers are gone.

**Image/Read Render Layers** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) does not recall them.

**Output/Cache Result** is enabled, and while I have an cache folder path defined, that folder yet remains empty.

Meanwhile ever since enabling **Output/Cache Result** my .blend files have grown from a few dozen MBs to half a gig each, so I'm assuming the render layers I'm seeking are buried somewhere in the .blend file, but again: How do I access them?

Comment: are you talking about [render layers](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html) or render passes (Color, alpha, Z, mist, etc.)?

Comment: You would have to setup the compositor to [save each render pass to a file](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27684/935).

Comment: David, correct: I'm talking about render passes (maybe I used the wrong term?)

Answer (score 1):

Render your image to OpenEXR MultiLayer format and save the image after rendering.

[image]

When saving the image, ensure you have the *composite node* connected and **not** a viewer node connected, or the layers will not write.

Doing this, you can open the image at any time for further post processing or grading by simply adding an *image node*, and you will have access to all the passes and render layers from the image.