# Is there a way to mute an operator's stdout prints?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I have a script that processes a mesh in various ways (shrinkwrap, bisect and other operations) and renders two images with freestyle.

These processes (and many others in blender) spew out various messages that clutter the standard output buffer and make debugging and logging quite difficult and annoying.

Rendering an image with freestyle, for instance, generates hundreds of printed lines that report the memory, which part is being rendered, etc.

Is there a way to silence all prints except my own debug prints?
I know I can probably write my stuff to a different stream like stderr but I'd really like to have more control over what's displayed and what's not.

Comment: Great! btw: thanks for your production scripts, also mentioned here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406.

Comment: Sure, good to know they're useful to other people :)