# How to do seperate render passes in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

I a lot of VFX breakdown that uses something they call "render passes". From what I see, they are rendering the clip in seperate ways (like rendering the ambient occlusion, specular, shadows, depth of field, etc individually and then combine it). Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Of course. But it really depends on the shot, your render engine and particularly on your further compositing/math workflow/skills whether this makes sense to do at all. For the most cases this is huge overhead, but if you really need full control about image color values [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406) could help implementing a workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your question is a [little bit vague](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you have everything you need to begin to understand this topic on the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/passes.html)

Short answer, because this is a huge topic, and your question implies that the concept itself isn't quite clear for you (the reason I advised you to first read the manual ;) ), but the concept is to :

- activate the needed passes in the `render layers` section

[image]

- use nodes to separate the different passes

[image]

This opens a lot of possibilities, because you can independently tweak every passes, export each ones to different locations, if you have just one parameter to modify, it doesn't need to re-render everything, etc...