# How to name an .exr file?

Tags: .exr

How do you name an .exr file? I saw how to rename each pass but I couldn't figure out how to name the overall file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you using a file output node to render an exr multilayer file? If yes, you can set the *file path* followed by the *name* in the node properties or in the node itself. Otherwise please add more context.

Comment: @poor I am using the file output node. Thanks for the help, I'm still a little new to the workflow still. It looks like if you are rendering a single channel format like .png you would name the file where it says "File Subpath" within the node. The multichannel .exr is a little different because there is no "File Subpath" but instead "Layers" and you name the main file in the path.

Comment: Again, png is a crappy file format. I'd suggest render as [multilayer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406). I'd like to help, but I still not understand your issue, can you elaborate? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @poor I was confused how to save the file name for a .exr file because the way to save the file name is different from saving a single channel file like png. When I saved it out, it would always render 0001.exr instead of "yourname".exr for example. You explained how to name exr files though so that answered the question. Thanks & sorry for the confusion.