# How do I encode an .exr image sequence?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, video, encoding

I have an animation that I want to render. I read up on the internet and saw an addon called [SID](https://gumroad.com/l/superimagedenoiser) that works great for denoising animations. My problem is that the add-on renders all the files into [.OpenEXR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) and I have no idea how to compile the image sequence into a video clip.

What program do I need to use to make these files a video? When I open the images they are all black. Do I have to re-render everything?

Comment: You can either use Blender's VSE, Blender's Compositor, Davinci Resolve, Fusion, Natron, Nuke... or even ffmpg can handle exrs.

Comment: @brockmann I'm really new to this and when I opened it into blender video sequencer they went all black. Any idea where I can watch a tutorial or have someone explain to me because i really can't orientate myself in these programs.

Comment: They probably didn't "go all black", they were already black before. How did you make those EXR files? Where did they come from? Have you seen their content correctly elsewhere? What is is SID addon you mentioned? This question is very lacking in detail and it is had to help you.

Comment: Don't have the time for a complete answer right now. Just load the image sequence in Blender's compositor and see whether it's still black or there are any other passes to work with. In general a more advanced topic, if you're new to this, here is a pretty nice overview: [Save all render passes to EXR image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image/18406#18406)