# How do I render out separate passes to be comped in After Effects?

Tags: rendering, render-passes

The passes I'll need are:

- Alpha
- RGB Colour
- Reflection
- Specular
- Ambient Occlusion
- Shadow

Cycles or Eevee, doesn't matter, but they'll need to be rendered out to be used in a different program (not comped in Blender, it's part of a pipeline).

What's the easiest way to get this done?

Comment: Emir, thank you for taking the time. Yes, it does answer my question, thank you very much! :)


In my searches I also found this tutorial (which uses v2.8+) and this seemed to be the most elegant method.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thc0-1ze8po


There's just so many ways to skin this cat with outputting files like this, so I appreciate the other methods you've posted.


It all helps. :)

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image/18406#18406